# Cannot use CSS in Reactjs SSR

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webpack

Hi there I am trying to apply custom CSS to my react component in React SSR project
however, it causes an error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js
Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "@babel/preset-env" relative to directory "R:\\Webdev\\AlmaJ\\server\\node_modules\\css-loader"
    at R:\Webdev\AlmaJ\server\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:293:19
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (R:\Webdev\AlmaJ\server\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:275:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (R:\Webdev\AlmaJ\server\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:264:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (R:\Webdev\AlmaJ\server\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:249:14)
    at OptionManager.init (R:\Webdev\AlmaJ\server\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)
    at File.initOptions (R:\Webdev\AlmaJ\server\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:212:65)
    at new File (R:\Webdev\AlmaJ\server\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (R:\Webdev\AlmaJ\server\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transpile (R:\Webdev\AlmaJ\server\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:50:20)
    at Object.module.exports (R:\Webdev\AlmaJ\server\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:175:20)
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/style.css 1:27-84
 @ ./src/style.css
 @ ./src/index.js
```

when I try to import a CSS file in a js file.

**my package.json file is here:**

```
"version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "AlmaJ ssr project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel dev:*",
    "dev:server": "nodemon --watch build --exec node build/bundle.js",
    "dev:build-server": "webpack --config webpack.server.js --watch",
    "dev:build-client": "webpack --config webpack.client.js --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.16.2",
    "babel-cli": "6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
    "compression": "1.7.0",
    "concurrently": "3.5.0",
    "css-loader": "2.1.0",
    "express": "4.15.4",
    "express-http-proxy": "1.0.6",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "nodemon": "1.12.0",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.1",
    "react": "16.3.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
    "react-dom": "16.0.0",
    "react-helmet": "5.2.0",
    "react-redux": "5.0.6",
    "react-router-config": "1.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "serialize-javascript": "1.4.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "webpack": "3.5.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.8.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "1.6.0"
  },
```

**here are my webpack files**

**webpack.server.js:**

```
const path = require("path");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const baseConfig = require("./webpack.base.js");
const webpackNodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

const config = {
  target: "node",
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
  },

  externals: [webpackNodeExternals()],
};

module.exports = merge(config, baseConfig);
```

**webpack.client.js:**

```
const path = require("path");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const baseConfig = require("./webpack.base.js");

const config = {
  entry: "./src/client/client.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
  },
};

module.exports = merge(config, baseConfig);
```

**webpack.base.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: "/node_modules/",

        options: {
          presets: [
            "react",
            "stage-0",
            ["env", { targets: { browsers: ["last 2 versions"] } }],
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I also tried to use styled-components

```
import styled from "styled-components";
const Some = styled.header`
  h1 {
    color: red;
  }
`;

<Some>
    <h1>hi</h1>
</Some>
```

The server runs before it gets a request from a browser but when the request comes in:

```
TypeError: element.type.toLowerCase is not a function
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.renderDOM (R:\Webdev\AlmaJ\server\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2776:28)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (R:\Webdev\AlmaJ\server\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2755:23)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (R:\Webdev\AlmaJ\server\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2722:19)
    at renderToString (R:\Webdev\AlmaJ\server\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2980:25)
    at exports.default (R:\Webdev\AlmaJ\server\build\bundle.js:396:44)
    at R:\Webdev\AlmaJ\server\build\bundle.js:329:42
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "R:/Webdev/AlmaJ/server/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js" as it exceeds the max of "500KB".
```

I've been spending so much time solving this problem,
I would really appreciate any help